# Relative path for <img> agnostic to <base> tag

Tags: html

I am a newbie with html so please excuse me if the question is dumb. I want to specify a path for an image (img src=...) relative to where my HTML resides. How would I do that. By default the relative path is considered relative to the base URL (base href=...)
I need it to work on both Chrome and IE on Windows

Before someone asks, obviously I need to set the base tag to some other location and hence am facing this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If my post answered your question, could you *accept* it? If not, is there any additional information I (or someone else) could provide to help you? See [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) in the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regrettably (or maybe not), there is no way to achieve this in pure HTML. Possible workarounds include either **not using a relative path** or **using JavaScript to generate an absolute path**.

Comment: Actually I have already started exploring the javascript option

Comment: Currently I am using var image_path = location.href.substring(0,location.href.lastIndexOf('/')+1); which is pretty yuck!

Comment: @Programmer12, unless you're using a backend language to generate the code (e.g. PHP), then this would be your best option (assuming you *cannot* simply use absolute paths instead).